# Exponential growth of $a^n + 2 Re(z^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm wondering if $a^n + 2 Re(z^n)$ ( a $\in [1,2]$ and z $\in \mathbb{C}$) have an exponential growth?

More precisely, a, z and $\overline{z}$ are roots of the polynomial function: f(x) = -x³+x²+x+1

Thanks you in advance

Comment: $a$ and $z$ are fixed and you're asking about exponential growth w.r.t. $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It grows as $a^n$ does, as $|z|<1$, the other term doesnt  matter much.